# Why is g++ not working?

Tags: c++, mingw

I am using MinGW and whenever I try to run g++ from the command line I get this pop up error:

> This application has failed to start because libgmp-10.dll was not found. Re-installing the application may fix this problem.

I checked and I found that there is in fact a file named libgmp-10.dll inside `MinGW/bin`. At first there wasn't but I downloaded the file and placed it in there. `MinGW/bin` must not be the correct place to put it because it still says that it cannot find the file.

So where do I place `libgmp-10.dll`?

**Update:** This is my `PATH` environment variable:

```
C:\MinGW\bin:
/c/Program Files/Vim/vim74:
/c/Program Files/Haskell/bin:
/c/Program Files/Haskell Platform/2013.2.0.0/lib/extralibs/bin:
/c/Program Files/Haskell Platform/2013.2.0.0/bin:
/c/WINDOWS/system32:
/c/WINDOWS:
/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:
/c/Program Files/QuickTime/QTSystem/:
/c/Program Files/TortoiseHg/:
/c/Program Files/Haskell Platform/2013.2.0.0/mingw/bin:
/c/Program Files/nodejs/:
/c/sbcl:
/c/emacs/bin:
/c/Documents and Settings/[my name]/Application Data/cabal/bin:
/c/Documents and Settings/[my name]/Application Data/npm:
.f
```

This is the contents of `MinGW`:

```
/MinGW
    /bin
    /include
    /libexec
    /msys
    /var
    /doc
    /lib
    /mingw32
    /share
```

This is inside `MinGW/bin`:

```
aclocal          autoreconf-2.68  ld.exe                    msgcat.exe
aclocal-1.10     autoscan         libcharset-1.dll          msgcmp.exe
aclocal-1.11     autoscan-2.13    libexpat-1.dll            msgcomm.exe
aclocal-1.4      autoscan-2.68    libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll        msgconv.exe
aclocal-1.5      autoupdate       libgettextlib-0-18-3.dll  msgen.exe
aclocal-1.6      autoupdate-2.13  libgettextpo-0.dll        msgexec.exe
aclocal-1.7      autoupdate-2.68  libgettextsrc-0-18-3.dll  msgfilter.exe
aclocal-1.8      c++.exe          libgmp-10.dll             msgfmt.exe
aclocal-1.9      c++filt.exe      libgmpxx-4.dll            msggrep.exe
addr2line.exe    cc.exe           libgomp-1.dll             msginit.exe
ar.exe           cpp.exe          libiconv-2.dll            msgmerge.exe
as.exe           dlltool.exe      libintl-8.dll             msgunfmt.exe
autoconf         dllwrap.exe      libltdl-7.dll             msguniq.exe
autoconf-2.13    elfedit.exe      libmpc-3.dll              ngettext.exe
autoconf-2.68    envsubst.exe     libmpfr-4.dll             nm.exe
autoheader       g++.exe          libquadmath-0.dll         objcopy.exe
autoheader-2.13  gcc-ar.exe       libssp-0.dll              objdump.exe
autoheader-2.68  gcc-nm.exe       libstdc++-6.dll           pthreadGC2.dll
autom4te         gcc-ranlib.exe   libtool                   pthreadGCE2.dll
autom4te-2.68    gcc.exe          libtoolize                ranlib.exe
automake         gcov.exe         mingw-get.exe             readelf.exe
automake-1.10    gdb.exe          mingw32-c++.exe           recode-sr-latin.exe
automake-1.11    gdbserver.exe    mingw32-cc.exe            size.exe
automake-1.4     gettext.exe      mingw32-g++.exe           strings.exe
automake-1.5     gettext.sh       mingw32-gcc-4.8.1.exe     strip.exe
automake-1.6     gettextize       mingw32-gcc-ar.exe        windmc.exe
automake-1.7     gprof.exe        mingw32-gcc-nm.exe        windres.exe
automake-1.8     iconv.exe        mingw32-gcc-ranlib.exe    xgettext.exe
automake-1.9     ifnames          mingw32-gcc.exe           zlib1.dll
autopoint        ifnames-2.13     mingw32-make.exe
autoreconf       ifnames-2.68     mingwm10.dll
autoreconf-2.13  ld.bfd.exe       msgattrib.exe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place it somewhere in your `PATH` environment variable.  Try sticking it (or a shortcut to it) in the same directory as your compiled executable.

**Note**: libgmp is used by g++, not your compiled executable.  g++ needs to find libgmp somewhere in your `PATH` or in the current working directory.  Place it in one of those two places and the compiler will work.

**Update**: You are missing several DLLs, this is called "DLL Hell".  The only real way to get around this is by following the instructions and doing a complete reinstall.

Comment: Would I have to do that for every program I make?

Comment: _"Would I have to do that for every program I make?"_ No you can set the `PATH` to find particular shared library installations, system wide.

Comment: The file `libgmp` was in `MinGW/bin` like I said and `MinGW/bin` is in the `PATH` environment variable but I still get the same error. I get the same error when I place the file in the same working directory but the file is named differently: `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll`

Comment: @templateboy libgcc_s is a different library, you have a problem where you are lacking several dlls all at once.  This is called "DLL Hell", the way you get out of it is by following the instructions and doing a complete reinstall.

Comment: @randomusername I uninstalled and reinstalled two times before but I got the same error. Maybe I wasn't doing it right: I moved the MinGW directory to the trash and deleted it from the trash. Then I went to a site to get the installer and downloaded everything again. But nonetheless it still doesn't work. Was that the right way?

Comment: @templateboy Edit your question to include the complete contents of the `PATH` variable as well as the literal content of the MinGW directory and MinGW/bin.  I need more information than this, cause it should work.

Comment: @randomusername There you go.

Comment: I figured out the problem. It was in my `Path` (not `PATH`) environment variable: I had a directory `c/cygwin/bin` which for some reason was messing with `g++`. Removing that path fixed the problem. Thanks for your help, it made me narrow down the problem!